# How do I distinguish between points created in cox.zph()?

Tags: cox-model

I've been developing a Cox Proportional Hazards model, coxPHDC, using the survival package in R. I then tested the proportional hazards assumption with

```r
    cox.zph(coxPHDC)

    zph1 <- cox.zph(coxPHDC, transform = function(time) log(time))

    plot(zph1[2])
```

and developed the following graph for temperature:
[image]

As you can see there are non-proportional hazards with temperature in my results. My data is split between two temperatures, 320 C and 340 C, and there look to be two different groups in the graph. Even if these two groups aren't defined specifically along temperature I want to see which points in this graph are 320 C and which are 340 C. How can I code that?

Answer (score 1):

The values on the y-axis are the scaled Schoenfeld residuals, available with `resid(coxPHDC, "scaledsch")`, so you can obtain and plot them separately from `plot.cox.zph`.

Note that (by definition) there is one scaled Schoenfeld residual *per event time*, not one per individual. If you have tied events, there isn't a unit mapping from individuals to points.